# pip3 packages are being installed in ~/.local folder

Tags: pip, python-3.8, path-variables, ubuntu-20.04

I recently upgraded to `ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. As `python3.8` was preinstalled, I installed pip using the command `sudo apt install python3-pip` , and I started installing python3 libraries. All the libraries I install are being installed into `~/.local/lib/Python3.8/site-packages` folder. If I remember correctly, these packages should be installed into `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`.

```
madhan@madhan:~$ pip3 show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.2.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/madhan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

After the packages are installed, I get a **warning** saying ~/.local/bin is not included in $PATH variable.

```
Installing collected packages: appdirs, cachelib, pygments, cssselect, lxml, pyquery, howdoi
  WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/home/madhan/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script howdoi is installed in '/home/madhan/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 cachelib-0.1 cssselect-1.1.0 howdoi-1.2.1 lxml-4.5.1 pygments-2.6.1 pyquery-1.4.1
```

even if ~/.local/bin is not included in $PATH variable, I am still able to import the packages.

```
madhan@madhan:~$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? How do I change the default folder to which pip3 packages are installed. Is it okay leave the packages in ~/.local folder or will it be a problem in the future?

Comment: its normal to install in local/lib is arent you using conda